# looping over followers name in instagram

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to generate a list where to put the followers name for a particular person using selenium into a list

[image]

The XPath for the first user in the list is :

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a
```

I been trying loop over li but could reach nothing good.

Or maybe i can take the tittle for each one of this class, but i cannot perform it

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: According to your screenshot you need to be looping over the anchor tags and not the list item tags.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish can easily be done in plain python:

1. Copy the page HTML into a text file
2. Extract all anchor tags using regex
3. For each anchor tag, if href value contains anchor text value, then append the anchor text to list of followers

Answer (score 0):

Try to post your code, so it would be easy for us to view and try to help you.

-HTML code
-Your code (java/python)

Answer (score 0):

After followers link clicked you need to wait until follower dialog appear, use `WebDriverWait`

```
# after the link clicked
followers = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    lambda d: d.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="dialog"]//a[@title]')
)
for follower in followers:
    print(follower.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

note: your xpath only return first follower